# Can I speed up showing tooltips in Dragon Age II?

Tags: dragon-age-2

*I feel like an idiot.*

When I hover over something, I like to see the tooltip for that thing immediately. In Dragon Age II, I have to wait like half a second.

Is there a way to remove the delay and make that instant? I searched through the options twice and couldn't find anything. But I could also be blind.

Comment: This seems like a local problem to me. Though there is no possibility to do this at the moment, it might change with a patch in the future. I know this happened in Neverwinter Nights 2 (Obisidian, though, not Bioware) at some point.

Comment: Have you tried trawling through the game files to see if there is a cunning `settings.ini` or similar you could edit perhaps? I didn't check my folder yet, been busy playing :D

Answer (score 2):

I, too, had issues with this. It wasn't terrible, though. It may be possible in the settings.ini file, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

I would keep checking the mod forum for Dragon Age II on the Bioware Community site, and [Dragon Age Nexus](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/cat.php?id=69) for a mod like this. I did however find a mod for DA2 which makes it so you don't have to always hold down the TAB button to see items on the ground ([here](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=2266)). It should make your life reasonably better until then.

I just finished a 30+ hour trek of the game. It was amazing, but short. Just gotta wait for that expansion now!